# selecting a specific project using $dte in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I am trying to unload a project using $dte powershell command. I am running this command from Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. I know I can unload the project using

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject")
```

But before this, I would have to select the project and I am unable to do the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically I am looking for the command to select a specific project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something resembling the following:

```
$dte.Solution.Projects | Where { $_.Name -imatch "DesiredProjectName" }
```

But I only referenced the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._dte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)